# MySQL query to fetch last record from each group involving 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm writing a MySQL (MariaDB) query fetch the list of senders from which a user has received message. Like in Facebook inbox, I want recent senders to appear first which I've already already via following query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT user_id_s
    FROM  messages
    WHERE  id IN (
        SELECT  MAX(id)
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  user_id_r=390
            GROUP BY  user_id_s
                 )
    order by  id DESC
```

It seems to work fine (not sure if it will work fine with large records like a million rows?). But the real problem is the it only fetches in order if the last message was received by a user and not the last replied.

Example:

User 390 has received messages from following users in this order:

1. 385
2. 421
3. 422
4. 423
5. 424
6. 429
7. 430
8. 431

So now user 431 is most recent and appears at top of the list, but if user 390 replied to user 431, it stays at bottom while I want this to appear at top based on the last interaction.

I hope I explained it well.

**EDIT:** Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82417/2

In this example, row id with '573' should appear at top replacing row# 572 and rest of the result must remain same. Also the second column which has user_id_s should give '431' at first row, just as it is now.

Comment: Because you order them by id, i.e. `order by id DESC`. IMHO, select will never fix the issue, and it will not scale. The right way to fix it is to create dynamic logic to put the message in desire sequence in static way.

Comment: @mootmoot Could you please elaborate "dynamic logic" part a bit? An example?

Comment: Visualise this as paper filing system. Convert the way of sorting and insert message into respective sequence into insert logic.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of "last":  Instead of `MAX(id)`, you need

```
SELECT id
    FROM messages
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY last_replied DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Scaling:  See [*Groupwise Max*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) .